# How to handle resource loading in a control that is packed into a nuget?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, .net-core

I'm working on a generic 'window control' as I find I do a lot of the same things in the desktop apps I work on. I have a small project with a control, designed to go in a window in another project. This worked fine when in different projects (but the same solution), but now I have moved the window control to a new solution and packed it into a nuget, then referenced the nuget in my project with the window.

On initialising the window, it complains it can't find a resource that the control uses. For theming, when the user sets a theme (and on startup) an image which will best suit the brightness of the theme colour is picked and applied to a UI bound BitmapImage property. This is the resource that the usage of the control in my window in another project can't find, I get this error:

[image: Exception on initialising window containing my window control from another solution]

To me it seems the application I am using the control in is trying to find the pngs in its own resources, rather than that of the nuget. But I'm unsure on how to ensure the nuget functions only internally.

The two images to pick from are both set as 'Resource' and not to copy to output. I have also tried solutions where the images are simply copied to the output and read in via a relative path, however this doesn't seem to work:

[image: Properties for my images the viewmodel picks from]

On setting the theme, this code runs:

```
ThemeImage = isThemeDark 
            ? new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/Pallete_Light.png", UriKind.Absolute))
            : new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/Pallete_Dark.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

This works fine on a test window in the same project as the control, the little colour pallete icon is the on being picked from:

[image: Colour palette icon visible when adding control to a window in same project]

My window is very simple, and is the same as the window from the project where it works.

```
<Window
    x:Class="SomeApplicationName.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeApplicationName" xmlns:win10themables="clr-namespace:Win10Themables;assembly=Win10Themables"
    Title="SomeApplicationName"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStyle="None"
    WindowState="{Binding ElementName=WindowControl, Path=DataContext.WindowStateProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <win10themables:MainWindowControl x:Name="WindowControl" Title="SomeApplicationName" />
</Window>
```

In my App.xaml, I simply merge some resource dictionaries from the project the window control comes from so this project can use them:

```
<Application
x:Class="SomeApplicationName.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Win10Themables;component/ResourceDictionaries/Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Win10Themables;component/ResourceDictionaries/Converters.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Win10Themables;component/ResourceDictionaries/Brushes.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Sorry for the code dump. I'm at a bit of a loss on how to resolve this. I wanted to avoid repeatedly copying the base window project into each of my new projects, but at this point might be forced to do so anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who runs into this issue, I resolved this by keeping the images as resources, but then adding the images to a resource dictionary and merging that into the app.xaml of the project with the control, and referencing the image through Application.Current.Resource["ImageResourceName"] and casting to the type of my property (BitmapImage).

In my application where I consume this nuget (and add the control to the window), I also merge this resource dictionary into my app.xaml. This seems to resolve the issue, though I can't entirely understand the difference between referring it via the projects resources, and the resource dictionary, and why the latter resolves this. If anyone viewing this with this answer has any light to shed on this for mine and anyone elses benefit, please do!